# Where can one find a free 'Basic French' word list?

Tags: lexique

I'm looking for a French lexicon that I can pass on to my pupils who have been asked to program a French-language "Hangman" game.

I have found a lexicon on the Internet but it is way too large (≈ 129K words), with many rare words that most teenagers don't know, and listing plurals of nouns and adjectives, as well as conjugated verbs, which are great for Scrabble but not suitable for Hangman. I just need 'Common French words'.

Admittedly, I don't know exactly what I mean by 'Common'. Perhaps the 5K most common words? Or the 10K?

Comment: Have you tried asking the question on [Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/)? I think your question would be much better there. The most common words for a French native aren't necessarily the most common for a non native learner. [Here](https://eduscol.education.fr/186/liste-de-frequence-lexicale) the 1500 most common words expected to be known by 7-8 year old French natives. [Here](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionnaire:Liste_de_1750_mots_fran%C3%A7ais_les_plus_courants), the most common 1750 words.

Comment: [Liste de vocabulaire français pour les débutants](https://www.mosalingua.com/blog/2020/09/30/vocabulaire-francais/). [750 words for 3 year olds](http://www.ac-grenoble.fr/ecole/74/maternelle.marnaz/IMG/pdf/Liste_de_750_mots_pour_les_3_ans.pdf).

Comment: I am a moderator on both French Language SE and Language Learning SE, and I can confirm @None's comment that your question would also be welcome on the latter site.

Comment: @Tsundoku As a mod can you transfer it to LL? Or would it need first for someone to ask for the question to be closed here?

Comment: @None I know, but since the OP has no account on Language Learning SE, I would like to know whether they are OK with migrating the question. Otherwise, it'll just be an orphaned question there.

Comment: @None. Thanks for the pointers. These list of words are exactly the kind of things I needed. They need a little editing to be turned into a list of simple (remove composed words) unaccented words, but this is a good exercise for beginners in programming.

Comment: The kids are French like me, we love these accents and maybe we'll continue using French. But when we play Hangman or Scrabble or crosswords the accents are omitted. I believe the same rule applies in e.g. Polish or Spanish, no? A list of accented words like the ones suggested by None is fine. The program that plays Hangman will just have to remove the accents as part of its processing.

Comment: @Lambie When people ask where they can find a specific type of resource, telling them to create it themselves is **not** a helpful response.

Comment: @Lambie "Actually, is asking for resources a valid question for this forum?" The appropriate response to that is casting a close vote with the reason that it is "off topic". Also, you have been around long enough to know that comments are not intended for discussions.

Comment: @Lambie To my understanding, telling someone to create the resource they are looking for is not "asking questions".

Comment: @Tsundoku Not at all. I made a suggestion (Why don't you etc. is a suggestion). I was perplexed that a French speaker would ask for a list of words and want ones without accents and think that the game cannot be transferred so it agrees with le génie de la langue français. There are all sorts of Jeu du Pendu in French online.

Answer (score 1):

you can use quizlet. It's free, and they have a lot of lexicons with flash cards that helps to memorize. It's available online, and they have an app for Android/iOS.

Here is one good example of a lexicon with 100 basic words.
https://quizlet.com/484664798/french-flash-cards/

But you can find more there.

Hope it helps.

Website
https://quizlet.com/

Link for the Android app
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.quizlet.quizletandroid&hl=en-GB

Link of the iOS app
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/quizlet-learn-with-flashcards/id546473125

Comment: That quizlet has tons of phrases and accents.